# What version of system.dll do I need to have to enable get{} and set{} properties on c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, compiler-errors, get

Hi I am a software programmer and hardware designer. I am having a problem with VISUAL BASIC software with C# language. Whenever I type get{} / set{} argument, an error interface detects an error. It says "The name "get" does not available on context. I dont know what to fix because I only learned C# when I thoroughly apply my skills from C++. I open numerous DLL on Microsoft and does not resolve anything. 1) Does it need new library? 2) Where can I download and install DLL (in safe mode) of get/set command for C#?

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever I type get{} / set{} argument, an error interface detects an error. It says "The name "get" does not available on context

The `get` and `set` keywords are recognized in the context of a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) or [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) definition in C#:

```
class MyType
{
  private string _myString;

  public string MyStringProperty
  {
    // this is a property definition, `get` and `set` are recognized in this context
    get { return _myString; }
    set { _myString = value; }
  }

  public char this[int i]
  {
    // this is an indexer definition, `get` and `set` are also recognized in this context
    get { return i >= 0 && i < _myString.Length ? _myString[i] : '\0'; }
  }
}
```

Comment: I thoroughly research on the answer on this day that you need C# 9.0 on .NET 5.X latest language to have the get{}/set{} feature. I have C# 7.0 on .NET 2.2 which having no technical support on latest update. Use syntax on library (using system;) found on Microsoft folder on ( C:// ). Thank you Mathias R. Jessen for the answer which is also vital on how it works.

Comment: Links: C# 9.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9

Comment: Links: C# 7.0 :https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/a-belated-welcome-to-c-7-3/

Comment: Links: C# update: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: @KentDevs I'm not sure I understand your comments - Properties have been a part of C# since version 1.0, and `get`/`set` definitions with separate accessors has been supported since C# 2.0

Comment: Ok thanks. Ill make a memo on that